# Driving DC LED Arrays with a 100W driver and a T junction

Tags: led-driver

I have a very simple yet frustrating problem. I am trying to drive two LED Lights from one driver, and are using a simple T junction to drive them Parrallel (as shown in the photo). When doing this at my desk, it works as it should and both lights draw power. The problem occurs when i take my little T junction wire to a shop I am trying to retro fit with a new light and when plugged in, only the existing light illuminates UNLESS I switch the polarity of the new light wires. Very strange! Any help on this topic would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If switching polarity makes the light work then the polarity was backwards. Was that what you were asking?

Comment: In situation 1, the polarity is wired as per specs of the T junction and both lights worked as they should. When I take the same wire to a store where I am trying to power a new light, as well as the existing, the system doesnt work UNLESS I switch the polarity as shown in fig 2. How come in the lab it works correctly but on location, I need to switch the polarity of the wires?

Comment: It is hard to guess why the polarity is backwards between the two sites without knowing anything about the source or sink of that current.  Link datasheets and take some photos of whatever those wires are going to.

Comment: polarity issues a part, paralleling led strings on a single current driver is generally problematic